# Getting device name in .NET Standard for all platforms

Tags: c#, .net-standard

In .NET Standard on Andorid `Environment.MachineName = "localhost"`

The library I am writing will be used on multiple platforms including .NET Framework 4.

While it is writted in .NET Standard it is has multiple target platforms.

Is there a way I can get the device name when this is ran on android without referencing the Xamarin packages?

Comment: .NET Standard [doesn't support .NET Old 4.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard). That runtime version isn't supported in general. The earliest supported .NET Framework version is 4.5.2.

Comment: This *sounds* like a scenario where you're going to use a Xamarin specific build and talk to `DeviceInfo.Name` (or whatever). Since you already need multi-targeting to reach .NET 4, this shouldn't be *too* awkward

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thats why its multi targeted the code just needs to be able to compile on both platforms.

Comment: @apc you can do that by targeting fresh .NET Standard and .NET Framework versions. No supported operating system requires .NET Framework 4.0 - the last one that did was Windows XP. The 4.x versions are binary replacements too, which means even if you think you target 4.0, the machine probably runs a newer version installed by Windows Update in the last 7 years

Comment: I know :(. We still have to support XP, we have customers with hundreds of these in factories, big risk and expense for them to upgrade. Its happening slowly but in the meantime...#

Comment: It might be that the device dosn't actually have a name. I'm falling back on MAC address for the present